# Why my ftp server doesnt work in passive mode but works in active mode?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

Trying to setup a FTP server on a EC2.
I have installed vsftp and followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-18-04)

When I try to connect with the `-p` option I cannot pass any command. Everything is smooth without it.

I have setup `vsftpd.conf`:

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
pasv_address=<my-ip>
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=50000
pasv_max_port=51000
port_enable=YES
```

And opened the port (20-21 && 50000-51000 using Terraform here)

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ftp_passive_port" {
  name = "ftp_passive_port"

  description = "Access to FTP passive"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.din_vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 50000
    to_port     = 51000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [...]
  }

  # Allow all outbound traffic.
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

I got this error :

```
Connected to xxxxxxxx.
220 Welcome to XXXXX FTP service.
Name (xxxxx:qwerty): xxxxxxxxxx
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,198,19).
ftp: connect: Connection refused
ftp> bye
221 Goodbye.
```